# Securing the Web API (Asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currently working with ASP.net Web API with [Authorize] Attributes. Now instead of using the conventional way, I'm calling the following method to provide me an access token using which I can access the Web API methods.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public object GetAccessToken(string Id, string UserName, string Email)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);

            oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName));
            oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Id));
            oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, Email));

            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties());

            DateTime currentUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
            //ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.AddSeconds(20);

            string accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
            Request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            // Create the response building a JSON object that mimics exactly the one issued by the default /Token endpoint
            JObject token = new JObject(
                new JProperty("userName", UserName),
                new JProperty("userId", Id),
                new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
                new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
                new JProperty("expires_in", currentUtc.AddSeconds(20).ToString()),
                new JProperty("issued", currentUtc.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'")),
                new JProperty("expires", currentUtc.AddSeconds(20).ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"))
            );
            return Ok(token);
        }
```

**NOTE:** This works fine.

The problem is that anyone can access this method just by simple HTTPost Request and have an access token as it is not secured.

Coming straight to the question: How can this method be made secure?

Comment: First a question: why? What value does it add to do it yourself? Second: given the parameters why don't you check them against a db or something? Add a password or something. Otherwise use IP restriction or something like that. Without more background like why, and who the target audience of this api is it is hard to come up with a decent answer.

Comment: @PeterBons The answer to your second question is that I can return an access token once a user successfully logs in but that raises another point, how would the LOGIN method be made secure? Its a trade off i guess.

Comment: Well, the `GetAccessToken` is the login method. And it should ask for something like a secret that only the client knows, like a password. It should verify that the credentials are correct and only then issue a token. Just like you would do with the standard /token endpoint flow.

Comment: @PeterBons Like adding some sort of a flag to the request? I thought of it as well, too bad the suggestion was not considered a good one. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Normally in the web api flow once you get a token the client has to pass it at each and every request so it can be checked whether it is valid or not. So my first question still stands, why all this trouble and not use the provided framework methods?

Comment: @PeterBons What value would it add to the scenario if i follow the provided framework methods than this one?

Comment: Well, it gives clear guidance on how it should be implemented, it would follow a standardized implementation that every (.net) developer would understand. Trying to develop around a framework seems like a waste of time to me. I would focus on the business issues instead.

Comment: @PeterBons, Your point is valid. But i'll still have to find a way to avoid giving each and every request an access token which CURRENTLY is the main hurdle. I'll prefer to focus on this for now!

Comment: Sorry, I am out. I still stand that if you follow the framework this would not be the issue. Good luck though!

Comment: @PeterBons Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Add a simple implementation of Basic HTTP Authentication using AuthorizationFilterAttribute. This link will get you started: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter

Comment: @Icryder Thank you for the link.

Comment: @peterBons i tried using the framework. Can you please clarify what should be the application flow? because in order to have an access token, one must call the REGISTER method of the account controller, after that, we pass the registered email in a request to \Token and we get an access token in response. Should the register method be customized as per my project users or what? Because it seems to make a .mdf file of its own BY DEFAULT. I hope i've made my point clear.